# node.js folder disappears from PATH after iterm session close

Tags: node.js, path, nvm

I have a problem installing node with nvm, after nvm install 0.11 my $PATH variable looks like.

```
/Users/clicker/.nvm/v0.11.14/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

But after iterm session close, or if I use my IDE terminal I see

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

nvm use 0.11 helps, but it's not really convenient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer by ljharb on nvm github

> Yes, that's how nvm works - it's always only for a single terminal
>   session.
>
> nvm alias default 0.11 will allow you to make 0.11 the default for new
>   terminals, and nvm which 0.11 will return the location of that node
>   binary.